# Series solution of $xy^{\prime \prime}+2y^{\prime}-xy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I get $r(r+1)=0$, $(r+1)(r+2)c_1=0$ and

$$c_{n+1}=\frac{c_{n-1}}{(n+1+r)(n+r+2)}$$

The first equation gives the indicial roots $r=-1$ and $r=0$. The case for  $r=0$ is fine.

For $r=-1$, I don't see how $c_1=0$ is implied by the second equation. The way I see it, since $1+r=0$ when $r=-1$, $c_1$ is not necessarily zero here, but this leads to a different solution to what is in the text book. What am I missing? Why is $c_1$ forced to be zero?

Comment: What's your initial/boundary conditions?

Comment: there are no conditions given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already found a basis solution for $r=0$, you need just one other. Setting $c_1$ in the case $r=-1$ to some non-zero value will just add a multiple of the first, $r=0$, basis solution, so nothing new gets found.

Note that your DE can be written as
$$
(xy)''-(xy)=0,
$$
so that the solution you find are $y_1(x)=\frac{\sinh(x)}{x}$ and $y_2(x)=\frac{\cosh(x)}{x}$.

---

A bit more generally, it is exceptional that the integer difference of the roots does not lead to a logarithmic component in one of the solutions. This can be justified for instance with the symmetric nature of the equation, it is invariant under time reversal. Thus one can look for even and odd solutions, and in the odd solution the even-index coefficients are all zero.

Comment: Thanks, I watched a video where $c_1$ was set to zero, which does not make sense or follow from logic. But after you mentioned the multiples, I tried it again and left $c_1$ as any constant, even non-zero, the multiples are then added at the last stage $y=Ay_1+By_2$ to be just one term, which seemed like $c_1$ was forced to be zero but that is really not the case.